# Could 'what' be a head of noun phrase?

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction

> I spent what little time I had with my family.

What is the 'what' role?

Comment: I'd say it must be a ***determiner***, since syntactically, semantically, and idiomatically, nothing really changes if we replace ***what*** with ***the***. And I don't think you could ever say the word ***the*** was the "head" of a noun phrase (so far as I know, the "head noun" of *[what] little time* or *dinner time* is ***time*** in both cases).

Comment: Could 'what' starts subordinate clause?

Comment: *I'm not sure **what you mean**.* I'm not really interested in grammatical terminology as such, but I think it's at least *possible* that the highlighted words in my preceding sentence would count as a "subordinate clause". Presumably if you're prepared to *ask* me that question, at least ***you*** know what you think a subordinate clause is.

Comment: "what" can be used to introduce a subordinate clause (in fact it usually is used that way), but this is *not* a subordinate clause in the case of the original example.  I agree with @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica that it is probably best interpreted as a determiner in that usage.